# Replace single_template filter with what for default posts?

Tags: theme-development, functions, templates, filters

I was going through a tutorial on [Justin Tadlock's blog](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/06/creating-single-post-templates-in-wordpress) but it uses the single_template filter, which was removed in 3.4. The codex says to use {$type}_template but if I use "post_template" with the code on that page it doesn't work.

Comment: post format is not good for you?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm wanting to add microformat data to existing review articles and it would be nice to clean up the single.php file. Ideally, this post category would be set up as a custom post type but I don't know if I want to go through converting them. I can do everything I need in the single.php template but was thinking the example in the linked blog article would be nice for organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers you want are in the code.  Meaning, you need to go exploring.

Your search should start with `wp-includes/template-loader.php`.  This is the very last file WordPress includes before the theme get's loaded.  it runs through a bunch of conditionals to check which type of page we're out and what template to fetch.

The relevant (offending?) line:

```
<?php
elseif ( is_single() && $template = get_single_template() ) :
```

Now that we know `get_single_template` fetches templates for single posts, we can go find that function in `wp-includes/template.php`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Retrieve path of single template in current or parent template.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_single_template() {
    $object = get_queried_object();

    $templates = array();

    $templates[] = "single-{$object->post_type}.php";
    $templates[] = "single.php";

    return get_query_template( 'single', $templates );
}
```

No filters yet, but you're starting to see how WP locates templates. Now we need to see what `get_query_template` does (`get_query_template` is also in `wp-includes/template.php`).

```
<?php
/**
 * Retrieve path to a template
 *
 * Used to quickly retrieve the path of a template without including the file
 * extension. It will also check the parent theme, if the file exists, with
 * the use of {@link locate_template()}. Allows for more generic template location
 * without the use of the other get_*_template() functions.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $type Filename without extension.
 * @param array $templates An optional list of template candidates
 * @return string Full path to file.
 */
function get_query_template( $type, $templates = array() ) {
    $type = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9-]+|', '', $type );

    if ( empty( $templates ) )
        $templates = array("{$type}.php");

    return apply_filters( "{$type}_template", locate_template( $templates ) );
}
```

The first argument is the type of template we're goign to be locating (`single` for this question) and the second is a series of templates to search.  This is the point where we stop. `locate_template` just searches the child and parent theme directories for each of the files in the `$templates` array -- it returns the file path if one is found or an empty string if it isn't.

Notice that `$type` in this function is "single".

I wrote all the above, so I could tell you that the filter is still `single_template`.  The actual string `single_template` is not found in the source, but the filter still exists (and [it works](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/pjaxy/blob/master/pjax.php#L210)).